# Concrete functions in logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In logic in CS by huth and ryan, I
have seen the word **concrete functions /elements ** while a model is being explained. I cannot get what the difference between a normal function and concrete one is. Can some one elaborate on it?

Comment: On which page did you see it?

Comment: Do you want the page no.?

Comment: Second edition, Page 124 while explaining about the definition of a model.

Comment: They are just using "concrete" in the everyday meaning of "specific"

Comment: In the next page he writes f, P are just symbols but fM and PM denote concrete functions, whats does that mean? I dont understand what f and P are correctly.

Comment: Also why is it that a concrete value is not a term, but an element of model. Shouldn't all concrete values be nullary functions and hence a term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a way (not very useful, IMO) to make a clear distinction between the *symbols* of the language, i.e. the set $\mathcal F$ of *function symbols* and the set $\mathcal P$ of *predicate symbols* and the "objects" of the domain of the model $\mathcal M$ :

> "concrete objects" can be mathematical objects, like *numbers* and "concrete functions" can be "ordinary" mathematical functions, like *sum*).

See page 125 :

> The distinction between $f$ and $f^{\mathcal M}$ and between $P$ and $P^{\mathcal M}$ is most important.
>
> The symbols $f$ and $P$ are just that: symbols, whereas $f^{\mathcal M}$ and
> $P^{\mathcal M}$ denote a concrete function (or element) and relation in a model $\mathcal M$, respectively.

This means that $f^{\mathcal M}$ and $P^{\mathcal M}$ are not part of the formal language of predicate logic but are part of the meta-language we are using to define the formal system itself and its semantical interpretation.